# How may I store a file path in my program's app.config file?

Tags: c#, app-config, filepath, winapp

I have written a C# program for saving and reading PDF files. The program saves the output files to the local computer's bin folder. I want my program to access files from a different computer.

I have heard about keeping a file path stored in the `app.config` of my program, but I don't know how to do this.

How may I store a file path in my program's app.config file?

Comment: I think you asked same question before. what's the thing you are not getting?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606955/how-implement-usercontrol-in-winforms-mvp-pattern

Comment: sorry I copy question wrong...I edit it

Answer (score 36):

You can store the file path in an `app.config` file by using this format:

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
  <add key="Path" value="\\ComputerName\ShareName"/>
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

You can then read the app settings stored there using the `ConfigurationManager` class.  You'll have to add a reference to `System.Configuration` in your project, and reference it in the code.

After that, your path can be read by accessing `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"]` - it will be a `string`.

Comment: As addition to your answer, when you need to put path to folder in value it could be in format like: "C:\Temp\Folder" (no need to escape backslash sign like "C:\\Temp\\Folder")

Answer (score 7):

I'm a complete noob but I recently had the same issue so here is what I came up with.

The solution is three separate steps:

1. As stated in the answer above, you add a key value to `app.config` that points to your path:

   ```
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="Path" value="C:\text.txt"/>
      </appSettings>
    </configuration>
   ```
2. You need the using statement:

   ```
   using System.Configuration;
   ```

Besides these two, you also need a reference to the assembly.

3. Right click on <kbd>References</kbd> in <kbd>Solution Explorer</kbd>.
4. Click <kbd>Add Reference</kbd>.
5. Click on <kbd>Assemblies</kbd> and type <kbd>Configuration</kbd> in the search box.
6. Put a check mark on <kbd>System.Configuration</kbd>.

The message

> ConfigurationManager does not exist in the current context.

should be gone and you have your file path!

Answer (score 0):

First: Create or Add app.config to your solution:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
     <add key="Path" value="C:\text.txt"/>
   </appSettings>
 </configuration>
```

Last:
Inside your winForm wirte these code:

```
string str= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Source"];
            MessageBox.Show(str);
MessageBox.Show(str);
```

That is allllll